# Docker Spark Master - Telnet Connection Refused on Port 7077 from Remote Machine

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I have set up a Spark cluster on a Linux machine using Docker. The IP address of the machine is 172.26.21.130. I used the following command to create the container:

```
sudo docker run -itd \
                --net=hadoop-net \
                -p 8080:8080 \
                -p 7077:7077 \
                -p 4040:4040 \
                -p 4041:4041 \
                -p 4042:4042 \
                --name spark-master \
                --hostname spark-master \
                spark-master
```

The Spark setup is successful, and I can access the Web UI at http://localhost:8080/. However, I am unable to access Spark from another machine. I can telnet to port 8080 from the other machine using the following command:

```
telnet 172.26.21.130 8080
```

But, I am unable to telnet to port 7077 using the following command:

```
telnet 172.26.21.130 7077
```

I have also disabled the firewall on the machine, but it did not solve the issue. When I run the command sudo lsof -i :7077, the result shows:

```
docker-pr 19005 root    4u  IPv4 199370      0t0  TCP *:7077 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 19012 root    4u  IPv6 197545      0t0  TCP *:7077 (LISTEN)
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please get a shell to the spark-master container, and make sure the spark Master process using the --ip 0.0.0.0 parameter, and the 7077 port is listen status like below:

```
# docker exec -it spark-master bash
root@spark-master:/# ps aux|grep spark
root           9  3.1  0.6 5439940 399412 ?      Sl   14:54   0:07 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/java -cp /spark/conf/:/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
root          97  0.0  0.0   9064   728 pts/0    S+   14:58   0:00 grep --color=auto spark
root@spark-master:/# netstat -nltp|grep 7077
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7077            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9/java
root@spark-master:/#
```

Comment: I ran "ps aux|grep spark" and the result shows (root         117  1.4  1.5 5125992 246856 pts/1  Sl   07:26   0:05 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -cp /usr/local/spark/conf/:/usr/local/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host spark-master --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
root         233  0.0  0.0  11288   968 pts/1    S+   07:33   0:00 grep --color=auto spark)

also ran "netstat -nltp|grep 7077"  and the result shows (tcp        0      0 10.0.1.26:7077          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      117/java        
)

Comment: please remove "--net=hadoop-net" from the command line, restart the spark-master and try again

Comment: I use "--net=hadoop-net" for the swarm. When I removed it worked. But if I delete it, other workers on other machines can't connect to it

Comment: Try to add this spark-master into the docker-compose.yaml file as a whole stack, don't start it from command line.